# Using Serilog to log Elasticsearch without Microsoft logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog

I managed to implement logging into Elasticsearch in localhost. However It logs any kind of activity from ASP.net Core. A simple program start logs around 20 entries. How could I log only my log entries I place into the code. Would need all the severities, so change min log level is not the solution.

```
private static void ConfigureLogging()
{
    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile(
            $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
            optional: true)
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(ConfigureElasticSink(configuration, environment))
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
}

private static ElasticsearchSinkOptions ConfigureElasticSink(IConfigurationRoot configuration, string environment)
{
    return new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        IndexFormat = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{environment?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}"
    };
}
```

Loggly has the similar solutions I would need: https://github.com/neutmute/loggly-csharp

Answer (score 0):

You can override the logging level of libraries outside of your code. This can be done in code or in your serilog config settings in your appsettings file. Here is an article that explains how. https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/